# Как передать HINSTANCE родительского окна дочернему окну?

Tags: c++, windows, окно

В ф-ии `int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hI, HINSTANCE hP, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdLine){}` создаётся главное - родительское окно.
Есть ф-я `LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {}` для создания дочерних окон.
Стоит задача: создать кнопки и флажки в дочернем окне с помощью ф-ии `WndProc`.
Трудность: не получается создать окна с помощью ф-ии `CreateWindow` в `WndProc`, т.к. для этого нужен `HINSTANCE` (`hInst`) родительского окна. Передать `HINSTANCE` в ф-ю `WndProc` мы не можем, т.к. ф-я `WndProc` принимает только 4 параметра (мы её сами даже не вызываем, её вызывает Windows при вызове ф-ии регистрации окна `RegClass` (код ниже)). Как быть я даже не знаю. Нашёл в инете решение - вызвать ф-ю `GetModuleHandleW(NULL);` и записать возвращаемое значение в переменную `HINSTANCE hInst = GetModuleHandleW(NULL);` Вроде бы работает, но я не уверен, что я правильно применил эту ф-ю. Требуется помощь знающих людей)

Код:

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define ID_BUTTON 2000
#define ID_ALL 4010

struct OneButton {
    long style;
    TCHAR text[30];
};
const int NN = 11;
OneButton flags[NN] = {
    BS_CHECKBOX, L"x 1", BS_CHECKBOX, L"x 2",
    BS_CHECKBOX, L"x 3", BS_CHECKBOX, L"x 4",
    BS_CHECKBOX, L"x 5", BS_CHECKBOX, L"x 6",
    BS_CHECKBOX, L"x 7", BS_CHECKBOX, L"x 8",
    BS_CHECKBOX, L"x 9", BS_CHECKBOX, L"x10",
    BS_CHECKBOX, L"Все"
};
OneButton GroupFlags = { BS_GROUPBOX, L"Второй множитель" };
OneButton button = { BS_PUSHBUTTON, L"Умножаем" };

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(
HWND hwnd,
UINT msg,
WPARAM wParam,
LPARAM lParam) {
    #define IDM_MULT_1 1001
    #define IDM_MULT_2 1002
    #define IDM_EXIT 1003
    #define IDM_ABOUT 1004
    static HMENU hMenu, hFirstMenu, hAbout;
    static HWND hGroupFlags, hflags[NN];
    LONG cxChar, cyChar, cx, cy;
    HINSTANCE hInst = GetModuleHandleW(NULL);

    switch (msg) {
        case WM_CREATE:

            HDC hdc;
            TEXTMETRIC tm;
            hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
            SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(SYSTEM_FONT));
            GetTextMetrics(hdc, &tm);
            cxChar = tm.tmAveCharWidth;
            cyChar = tm.tmHeight;
            cx = tm.tmAveCharWidth;
            cy = tm.tmHeight + tm.tmExternalLeading;
            SetBkColor(hdc, GetSysColor(COLOR_BTNFACE));
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

            hGroupFlags = CreateWindow(
                L"button", GroupFlags.text,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | GroupFlags.style,
                cxChar, cyChar,
                21 * cxChar, 7 * cyChar + 5,
                hwnd, 0, hInst, NULL
            );
            cxChar = tm.tmAveCharWidth + 5;
            cyChar = tm.tmHeight * 2;
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < NN / 2; i++)
                hflags[i] = CreateWindow(
                    L"button", flags[i].text,
                    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | flags[i].style,
                    cxChar, cyChar + tm.tmHeight * i,
                    60, cyChar / 2,
                    hwnd, (HMENU)(4000 + i), hInst, NULL);
            cxChar = tm.tmAveCharWidth + 85;
            cyChar = tm.tmHeight * 2;
            for (i = 5; i < NN; i++)
                hflags[i] = CreateWindow(
                    L"button", flags[i].text,
                    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | flags[i].style,
                    cxChar, cyChar + tm.tmHeight*(i - 5),
                    60, cyChar / 2,
                    hwnd, (HMENU)(4000 + i), hInst, NULL);
            static HWND hLabel;
            cxChar = tm.tmAveCharWidth + 160;
            cyChar = tm.tmHeight;
            hLabel = CreateWindow(
                L"static", L"Второй множитель", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                cxChar, cyChar,
                160, cyChar + tm.tmHeight / 2, hwnd, 0, hInst, NULL);
            static HWND hButton;
            cxChar = tm.tmAveCharWidth + 160;
            cyChar = tm.tmHeight * 6 + 5;
            hButton = CreateWindow(
                L"button", button.text,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | button.style,
                cxChar, cyChar,
                160, 2 * tm.tmHeight,
                hwnd, (HMENU)ID_BUTTON, hInst, NULL);

        MessageBox(hwnd, L"Сообщение WM_CREATE",
            L"Начало!",
            MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
        hMenu = CreateMenu();
        hFirstMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
        AppendMenu(hFirstMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_MULT_1, L"Умножаем по-одному");
        AppendMenu(hFirstMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_MULT_2, L"Умножаем всё");
        AppendMenu(hFirstMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, NULL);
        AppendMenu(hFirstMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_EXIT, L"Выход");
        AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT)hFirstMenu, L"Множим");
        hAbout = CreatePopupMenu();
        AppendMenu(hAbout, MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUT, L"О программе");
        AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT)hAbout, L"?");
        SetMenu(hwnd, hMenu);
        DrawMenuBar(hwnd);
        return 0;
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            MessageBox(hwnd, L"Сообщение WM_LBUTTONDOWN", L"Выполняем!",
                MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        return 0;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            MessageBox(hwnd, L"Сообщение WM_DESTROY", L"Конец!",
                MB_OK | MB_ICONQUESTION);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL RegClass(HINSTANCE hInst, WNDPROC WndProc, LPCTSTR szName) {
    WNDCLASS wc;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = szName;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH);
    wc.cbClsExtra = wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    return (RegisterClass(&wc) != 0);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hI, HINSTANCE hP, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdLine) {
    MSG msg;
    HWND hwnd;
    TCHAR szClassName[] = L"FirstProgram";
    if (!RegClass(hI, WndProc, szClassName)) return FALSE;
    hwnd = CreateWindow(
        szClassName,
        L"Таблица умножения",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        0,
        0,
        hI,
        NULL
    );
    if (!hwnd) return FALSE;
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: А почему просто не сохранить параметр `HINSTANCE` в глобальную переменную?

Comment: Да, как вариант. Но всегда ли в разработке для Windows приходится пользоваться глобальными переменными для создания дочерних окон?

Comment: Этот параметр вам специально передается, чтобы вы его где-то сохранили и пользовались

Comment: Понял вас, программа работает корректно. Спасибо

Comment: Во время работы, в любое время можно узнать значение hInstance для конкретного Handle окна вызвав [GetClassLong](http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlong) GWL_HINSTANCE

Answer (score 2):

Никакие глобальные переменные не нужны. В обработчике `WM_CREATE` в оконной процедуре есть доступ к `HINSTANCE` создаваемого окна через `lparam`:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc
(
    HWND hwnd
,   UINT msg
,   WPARAM wParam
,   LPARAM lParam
)
{
    LRESULT result{};
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            if(0 != lParam)
            {
                auto const & cp{*reinterpret_cast<LPCREATESTRUCTW>(lParam)};
                // cp.hInstance contains HINSTANCE of the window being created
            }
            else
            {
                result = -1; // a failure
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @Abyx Здесь класс окна не ищется, а HISTANCE используется для создания дочерних окон. Кроме того, в WM_CREATE он передается в любом случае.

Comment: @Abyx Для вызова `CreateWindow`, в вопросе же приведен код.

Comment: @Abyx Но здесь нет ни DLL, ни регистрации каких-то дополнительных оконных классов. Собственно вопрос был в получении `HISTANCE` родительского окна при создании дочерних в `WM_CREATE` - я на него ответил.

Answer (score 0):

`hInstance` - это адрес модуля, .exe или .dll.

Он нужен при регистрации класса окна, чтобы указать какому модулю принадлежит класс, т.к. две разных .dll могут зарегистрировать класс с одним и тем же именем.

И он нужен при создании окна, чтобы вместе с именем класса однозначно определить какой именно это класс окна (т.к. названия могут повторяться).

Т.к. когда вы создаете главное окно с вашим классом "FirstProgram", в `CreateWindow` надо передать именно тот `hInstance`, который был передан при регистрации класса в `RegisterClass`.

Однако, если класс окна глобальный (с флагом `CS_GLOBALCLASS`), как например системные классы `"button"`, `"static"` и т.п., то при создании окна можно передавать любой `hInstance` (и может даже и 0, но это не точно).

---

Теперь еще раз где взять `hInstance`.
Это адрес модуля. Его можно получить через `GetModuleHandle`, его передают в `WinMain` и `DllMain`, его можно получить через переменную `__ImageBase`, которая расположена в начале модуля (она определяется линкером).

```
extern "C" IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
HINSTANCE hInst = (HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase;
```

Comment: `extern "C" IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;` - Ну это же вообще треш.

Comment: Волшебные переменные с C-Style cast когда `HINSTANCE` и так передается в явном виде - это нельзя назвать иначе как треш...

Answer (score -1):

Самым простым решением стало создание глобальной переменной (`HINSTANCE hInst;`) и использование её для созранения handle приложения.

```
 #define UNICODE
    #define _UNICODE
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <tchar.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    #define ID_BUTTON 2000
    #define ID_ALL 4010

    HINSTANCE hInst;

    struct OneButton {
        long style;
        TCHAR text[30];
    };
    const int NN = 11;
    OneButton flags[NN] = {
        BS_CHECKBOX, L"x 1", BS_CHECKBOX, L"x 2",
        BS_CHECKBOX, L"x 3", BS_CHECKBOX, L"x 4",
        BS_CHECKBOX, L"x 5", BS_CHECKBOX, L"x 6",
        BS_CHECKBOX, L"x 7", BS_CHECKBOX, L"x 8",
        BS_CHECKBOX, L"x 9", BS_CHECKBOX, L"x10",
        BS_CHECKBOX, L"Все"
    };
    OneButton GroupFlags = { BS_GROUPBOX, L"Второй множитель" };
    OneButton button = { BS_PUSHBUTTON, L"Умножаем" };

    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(
        HWND hwnd,
        UINT msg,
        WPARAM wParam,
        LPARAM lParam) {
    #define IDM_MULT_1 1001
    #define IDM_MULT_2 1002
    #define IDM_EXIT 1003
    #define IDM_ABOUT 1004
        static HMENU hMenu, hFirstMenu, hAbout;
        static HWND hGroupFlags, hflags[NN];
        LONG cxChar, cyChar, cx, cy;

        switch (msg) {
        case WM_CREATE:

            HDC hdc;
            TEXTMETRIC tm;
            hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
            SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(SYSTEM_FONT));
            GetTextMetrics(hdc, &tm);
            cxChar = tm.tmAveCharWidth;
            cyChar = tm.tmHeight;
            cx = tm.tmAveCharWidth;
            cy = tm.tmHeight + tm.tmExternalLeading;
            SetBkColor(hdc, GetSysColor(LTGRAY_BRUSH));
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

            hGroupFlags = CreateWindow(
                L"button", GroupFlags.text,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | GroupFlags.style,
                cxChar, cyChar,
                21 * cxChar, 7 * cyChar + 5,
                hwnd, 0, hInst, NULL
            );
            cxChar = tm.tmAveCharWidth + 5;
            cyChar = tm.tmHeight * 2;
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < NN / 2; i++)
                hflags[i] = CreateWindow(
                    L"button", flags[i].text,
                    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | flags[i].style,
                    cxChar, cyChar + tm.tmHeight * i,
                    60, cyChar / 2,
                    hwnd, (HMENU)(4000 + i), hInst, NULL);
            cxChar = tm.tmAveCharWidth + 85;
            cyChar = tm.tmHeight * 2;

            for (i = 5; i < NN; i++)
                hflags[i] = CreateWindow(
                    L"button", flags[i].text,
                    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | flags[i].style,
                    cxChar, cyChar + tm.tmHeight*(i - 5),
                    60, cyChar / 2,
                    hwnd, (HMENU)(4000 + i), hInst, NULL);

            static HWND hLabel;
            cxChar = tm.tmAveCharWidth + 160;
            cyChar = tm.tmHeight;
            hLabel = CreateWindow(
                L"static", L"Первый множитель", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                cxChar, cyChar,
                160, cyChar + tm.tmHeight / 2, hwnd, 0, hInst, NULL);
            static HWND hButton;
            cxChar = tm.tmAveCharWidth + 160;
            cyChar = tm.tmHeight * 6 + 5;
            hButton = CreateWindow(
                L"button", button.text,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | button.style,
                cxChar, cyChar,
                160, 2 * tm.tmHeight,
                hwnd, (HMENU)ID_BUTTON, hInst, NULL);

            MessageBox(hwnd, L"Сообщение WM_CREATE",
                L"Начало!",
                MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
            hMenu = CreateMenu();
            hFirstMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
            AppendMenu(hFirstMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_MULT_1, L"Умножаем по-одному");
            AppendMenu(hFirstMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_MULT_2, L"Умножаем всё");
            AppendMenu(hFirstMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, NULL);
            AppendMenu(hFirstMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_EXIT, L"Выход");
            AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT)hFirstMenu, L"Множим");
            hAbout = CreatePopupMenu();
            AppendMenu(hAbout, MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUT, L"О программе");
            AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT)hAbout, L"?");
            SetMenu(hwnd, hMenu);
            DrawMenuBar(hwnd);
            return 0;
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            MessageBox(hwnd, L"Сообщение WM_LBUTTONDOWN", L"Выполняем!",
                MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            return 0;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            MessageBox(hwnd, L"Сообщение WM_DESTROY", L"Конец!",
                MB_OK | MB_ICONQUESTION);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    BOOL RegClass(HINSTANCE hInst, WNDPROC WndProc, LPCTSTR szName) {
        WNDCLASS wc;
        wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
        wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        wc.lpszClassName = szName;
        wc.hInstance = hInst;
        wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH);
        wc.cbClsExtra = wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
        return (RegisterClass(&wc) != 0);
    }

    int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hI, HINSTANCE hP, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdLine) {
        MSG msg;
        HWND hwnd;
        hInst = hI;
        TCHAR szClassName[] = L"FirstProgram";
        if (!RegClass(hI, WndProc, szClassName)) return FALSE;
        hwnd = CreateWindow(
            szClassName,
            L"Таблица умножения",
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
            0,
            0,
            hI,
            NULL
        );
        if (!hwnd) return FALSE;
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        return msg.wParam;
    }
```